# How to install XGBoost in windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows-installer, xgboost

While installing XGBoost for python 36 getting below error

C:\Users\Shrey Shivam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
Running from scipy source directory.
**error: no lapack/blas resources found**

Please let me know how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

You can look up this site for installation guides:

http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html

First you need to download the package from git and locally build it.
Then, you'll have to install the pythons package.